# Extra white spaces between header and refreshcontrol

Tags: ios, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I develop app with tableview where user can pull to refresh.

When i pull table down, i got extra space between header and refresh control.

[image]

I set `UIRefreshcontrol` and header background insid `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getLatestLoans];
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIHelper BaseColor];
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(getLatestLoans)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIHelper BaseColor]];
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest fix would be to change a background color of tableView to this blue color.

Comment: It's solved the problem, but added one more. When the table is empty i would to show message on the grey background

Comment: Hmm you can introduce logic to switch background back to grey color or show your empty data message on a new view with your grey color.

Comment: What if the header and background are different color? I support that this helped in this case but this is not general answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a groupped tableview you must set tableview background color to blue. If u dont, then show us some code.